# Visual Studio Code - EPERM error In Functions folder of Azure Local Workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've tried using Visual Studio Code with my regular user account and also my elevated account. Both ways seem to produce the same EPERM error in the local Azure Workspace.
I'm wondering if anyone would know how to clear this error so that I can finally get to synching my local resources with my remote account.

[Azure Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uaSH.png)

I tried to create an HTTP1 Trigger Function in the Local Workspace.

Comment: visual studio and visual studio code are totally different applications. Please [edit] to stop contradicting yourself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.